# splitting a matlab matrix into several equal parts

Tags: matlab, matrix, k-means

I have a matrix of size `64500x17`. It represents detected texton features that I have to use to find 5 centroids for `kmeans`.

What I need is:

- split this matrix into 5 `12900x17` matrices
- find the means
- concatenate these into a `5x17` matrix to feed in to the start parameter of `kmeans`.

I know how to do almost everything (`cat`, `kmeans`, etc), but I am merely trying to find a method for splitting the matrix into 5 parts, or summing/dividing into the desired size.

I am forbidden from overusing for loops (due to efficiency), unless absolutely necessary.

I can't find any pertinent example in other questions, so if this has been answered, please bear with me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mat2cell` and this oneliner

```
C = mat2cell(A, repmat(12900, 5, 1), 17);
```

The second parameter to `mat2cell` is the row split of the matrix.

Now `C` is a cell array:

```
C = 

[12900x17 double]
[12900x17 double]
[12900x17 double]
[12900x17 double]
[12900x17 double]
```

and the partial matrices can be accessed as

```
C{1} etc.
```

Comment: `repmat` or `12900*ones(5,1)`

Answer (score 3):

Just use indexing and store the extracted matrices in cells for easier handling:

```
data = rand(64500,17);
Nsubsets = 5;
Nsubsize = size(data,1)/Nsubsets;

splitted_data = cell(Nsubsets ,1);
splitted_data_means = cell(Nsubsets,1);

for ii=1:Nsubsets 
    splitted_data{ii} = data((ii-1)*Nsubsize + (1:Nsubsize),:);
    splitted_data_means{ii} = mean(splitted_data{ii});
end
```

you can then join these means with:

```
joined_means = cell2mat(splitted_data_means);
```

Or just for the heck-of-it with the one-liner:

```
joined_means = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(ii) mean(data((ii-1)*12900+(1:12900),:)),(1:5)','uni',false));
```

which would be even simpler with @angainor's `mat2cell`:

```
joined_means = cell2mat(cellfun(@mean,mat2cell(data, 12900*ones(5,1), 17),'uni',false));
```

Answer (score 1):

To take the first submatrix use colon notation:

```
A(1:12900,:)
```

then

```
A(12901:12900*2,:)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The probably fastest solution is:

```
data = rand(64500,17);
Nsubsets = 5;
Nsubsize = size(data,1)/Nsubsets;
joined_means=squeeze(mean(reshape(data,Nsubsize,Nsubsets,size(data,2)),1));
```

Split the first and second dimension, then you can calculate the mean over the first dimension of Nsubsets elements each.