# Splitting & evaluating a Matlab Matrix (parfor)

Tags: matlab, matrix, parfor

Is there any workaround to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13752864/2349516) procedure to work with `parfor` instead of classic `for`.

I have a matrix of size 10518300x8.

What I need is:

- split a matrix into 100 105183x8 matrices
- do some stuff -> output 5 different 100 105183x8 matrices.
- concatenate the upper 5 matricies into five 10518300x8 matrix.

I am forbidden from overusing for loops (due to efficiency), unless absolutely necessary. [**Gunther Struyf**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752511/splitting-a-matlab-matrix-into-several-equal-parts) solved, using `for`, like this:

```
data = rand(10518300,8);
Nsubsets = 100;
Nsubsize = size(data,1)/Nsubsets;

splitted_data = cell(Nsubsets ,1);
splitted_data_means = cell(Nsubsets,1);

for ii=1:Nsubsets 
    splitted_data{ii} = data((ii-1)*Nsubsize + (1:Nsubsize),:);
    splitted_data_means{ii} = mean(splitted_data{ii});
end

joined_means = cell2mat(splitted_data_means);
```

Any thoughts about adapting or finding another way to be able to use `parfor`?

Comment: Why are you unable to use `parfor`? I don't see any error. Besides this, using `parfor` will result in a high amount of communication but low complexity of calculation on the workers, this is typically slow!

Comment: I have written another answer the first question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22375889/2732801 This should be much faster than the already existing ones.