# How can I select a specific number of rows from a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose, I have a matrix loaded in MATLAB which has 1822 rows and 3 columns.

I want to select 1/10 th of the total rows from that matrix.

I tried the following,

```
>> train(size(train,1)/10,:)
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

Obviously, it didn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: try `help size`

Comment: something like ? `mymat(1: floor(size(mymat,1)/10),:)` 1/10 of 1822 is 182.2, I suppose you will be rounding down using the floor function.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, size returns two values.

Comment: @anonymous Of course it returns two values by default, this is well described in the help documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a matlab matrix into several equal parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752511/splitting-a-matlab-matrix-into-several-equal-parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You division is returning a float, and as the error clearly states:

```
 error: subscript indices must be either positive integers less than 2^31 or logicals
```

However, even if `size(train,1)/10` was an integer, it would not work as you wish to, because it would only return the 10th % row, and not all the elements until the 10th % row.

You need a integer and slice it from the first element, then just to truncate the number as stated by @GameOfThrows.

```
 >> train(1: fix(size(train,1)/10), :)
```

Here:

1. The last `, :` selects all columns from the target rows.
2. The first `1: fix(size(train,1)/10),`  selects all lines form the first line `1` until the 10th % row `fix(size(train,1)/10)`.

Comment: What can I do, If I want last 1/10th rows?

Comment: @anonymous if you want to select each slice, it is better to look at the duplicate solution I indicated.

Comment: @anonymous It is the opposite: `train(fix(size(train,1)/10): end, :)`

Comment: if you want the last 1/10th rows you need to start at `fix(9*size(train,1)/10)` otherwise you will take the last 9/10th rows

Answer (score 0):

```
mymat(1: floor(size(mymat,1)/10),:)
```

So the comment posted by `@GameOfThrows` actually worked.

Comment: :D "actually worked" - sounds like you are surprised it works, lol